# Are the compiler-inserted methods (through type erasure) volatile?

Tags: java, debugging, generics, reflection

[Essential Java Generics](http://anders.janmyr.com/2006/11/essential-java-generics.html) states that the output for this code:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    void foo(T param);
}

public class Bar implements Foo<Bar> {
    // This method will appear twice once with Object as parameter and once with Bar.
    public void foo(Bar param) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method m : Bar.class.getMethods())
            if (m.getName().startsWith("foo"))
                System.out.println(m.toGenericString());
    }
}
```

is:

```
public void Bar.foo(Bar)
public volatile void Bar.foo(java.lang.Object)
```

But when I compiled (1.7 compiler) and run the code, I have:

```
public void Bar.foo(Bar)
public void Bar.foo(java.lang.Object)
```

I re-compiled it using a 1.6 compiler. But my output is still the same.

The author's exact quote is:

> ```
> $ java Bar
> public void Bar.foo(Bar)
> public volatile void Bar.foo(java.lang.Object)
> ```

So it doesn't seem like a typo error on his part.

What is causing the output to be different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is no such thing as a volatile method in Java.** Only fields can be volatile.

See [Why make a method volatile in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651867/why-make-a-method-volatile-in-java) for further details.

As the top answer there explains, the same bit mask (`0x00000040`) is used for different purposes for fields and for methods. This confuses some older Java tools, causing them to incorrectly mark [bridge methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289745/367273) as `volatile`.

In other words, there was a bug in the software that the blog writer was using at the time, causing the software to mistakenly include the `volatile` in the printout. [The bug got fixed](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6261502), and you're not seeing the erroneous modifier anymore.

Comment: Are you saying that the writer of that blogpost made a mistake?

Comment: @Pacerier: What I am saying is that in this context, `volatile` is a red herring.

Comment: Ok just to make sure I understand you, you are saying that the writer made a typo mistake as the output would never have had been `public volatile void Bar.foo(java.lang.Object)` ?

Comment: @Pacerier: I've expanded the answer in an attempt to make it clearer. The method in question is what's known as a bridge method, and some tools are a bit buggy in that they display bridge methods as `volatile` (again, there's no such thing as a volatile method).